# Using jq to merge child files into a master file

Tags: json, merge, jq

There are plenty of `jq`-related questions about merging JSON documents, but they all seem to be about merging documents with the same structure.

My problem is different, in that I need to merge child documents into a parent document, where the child and parent documents have a different structure.

The parent document looks like this:

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "child0",
      "properties": {
        "template": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child1",
      "properties": {
        "template": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "child2",
      "properties": {
        "template": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need to do is merge in child documents at `.resources[].properties.template`, such that the first file is at `.resources[0].properties.template`, the second file is at `.resources[1].properties.template` etc.

Note the structure of the child documents is not important here, as I want to merge them in their entirety.

I have actually got this to work, but using multiple commands:

```sh
jq '.resources[0].properties.template += input' main.json child0.json > temp0.json
jq '.resources[1].properties.template += input' temp0.json child1.json > temp1.json
jq '.resources[2].properties.template += input' temp1.json child2.json > temp2.json
mv temp2.json merged.json
rm temp*.json
```

This is pretty ugly - I'm looking for a single `jq` command that can merge in the child files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Assuming the number of objects in `resources` equals the number of child documents, this should do the trick:

```
jq '.resources[].properties.template |= . + input' parent children...
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/EEBSWKECsF)</sup>

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I really seem to struggle with jq for some reason :/

Comment: @OguzIsmail - Perfect!

Comment: @peak thank you, didn't understand why `+=` didn't work though